# Cannot connect to Node Manager [Security:090476]

Tags: ssl, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I have two laptops which are connected via wireless router. Both can ping each other. I have started the `node manager` in one m/c. When I am trying to connect with the node manager from the other machine I am getting the exception

> WLSTException: Error occured while performing nmConnect : Cannot
>   connect to Node  Manager. : [Security:090476]Invalid/unknown SSL
>   header was received from peer D ESKTOP-HUCQUK5 - 192.168.0.5 during
>   SSL handshake.

`192.168.0.5` is the i.p of the m/c where my node manager is running.

I have made the `securedlistener` property in the node manager as false. 
I have also changed the type as plain in the weblogic admin console.
But still I am getting the same result